# Bootstrap 3 - Collapsible right-side panel like Google Drive Details/Activity panel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Working on a new web layout for our existing product.  We'd like the integrated team chat and activity feed displays to be consistently displayed on the right side of each page.  We're using Bootstrap 3 and I've got a mock that looks pretty good.  I'm using vanilla Bootstrap 12-column sizing styles to do this:

[image: current mock with right-side panel displayed]

Now we want to allow users to collapse that right-side panel (horizontally), especially for views where horizontal real estate is important (grid views, etc.).

Is there a Bootstrap way to do this?  I'm fine with a vertical splitter widget, or a toggle button in the top nav, or whatever other presentation makes sense.  It's more the grid sizing that I need advice on.

Comment: Have you looked at the off canvas example? http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

Comment: Thanks.  I took a look just now and it's close but I want the expanded section to compress the main display area, not slide it off the page.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had needed a similar approach to one of our projects and fullscreen view is [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravimallya/Y7P7h/6/show/).

I modified the script and layout a bit to get what you trying to achieve. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/4hpLx/3/) is the code and fullscreen is [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ravimallya/4hpLx/3/show/). I used jquery cookie to retain the view state even after page refresh. Clicking on the **Cog Icon** will toggle the sidebar. The script is:

```
    $(function () {
        var $menu = $('#sidebar-wrapper');
        var $content = $('#main-wrapper');
        if ($.cookie('offcanvas') == 'hide') {
            $content.addClass('no-transition');
            $menu.hide();
            $menu.css('right', -($menu.outerWidth() + 10));
            $content.removeClass('col-md-10').addClass('col-md-12');
        }
        else if ($.cookie('offcanvas') == 'show') {
            $menu.show(500).animate({ right: 0 });
            //  $menu.show();
            $content.removeClass('no-transition');
            $content.removeClass('col-md-12').addClass('col-md-10');
        }


        $('.toggle-button').click(function () {
            $content.removeClass('no-transition');
            if ($menu.is(':visible') && $content.hasClass('col-md-10')) {
                // Slide out
                $menu.animate({
                    right: -($menu.outerWidth() + 10)
                }, function () {
                    $menu.hide(1000);
                });
                $content.removeClass('col-md-10').addClass('col-md-12');
                $.cookie('offcanvas', 'hide');
            }
            else {
                // Slide in
                $menu.show(500).animate({ right: 0 });
                $content.removeClass('col-md-12').addClass('col-md-10');
                $.cookie('offcanvas', 'show');
            }
            if ($content.hasClass('col-md-12') && $menu.is(':hidden')) {
                $menu.animate({
                    right: 0
                }, function () {
                    $menu.show(1000);
                });
                //  $menu.show();
                $content.removeClass('no-transition');
                $content.removeClass('col-md-12').addClass('col-md-10');
            }
        });
        $('.bs-tooltip').tooltip();
    });
```

You can customize the layout/css to get what exactly you wanted to get.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind.  I'll flip the layout and animation to the right-hand side and it should be perfect.

Comment: my bad, marked the answer but didn't click the bounty!

Answer (score 5):

I just accomplished what I think you want with jquery adding and removing the bootstrap classes. I have a button with id `collapse` and when clicked it checks if the sidebar is open or not and makes changes to the layout.
The Markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><button class="btn-primary btn-large btn" id="collapse">Collapse sidebar</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8" id="content" style="height:400px;border:2px solid black">Hello, I'm a 3/4 width Div.</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 open" id="sidebar"  style="height:400px;border:2px solid blue">Hey There, I'm a 1/4 width Div</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$('#collapse').click(function(){
    if($('#sidebar').hasClass('open'))
    {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('col-md-4');
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('open');
        $('#sidebar').addClass('hidden');
        $('#content').addClass('col-md-12');
        $('#content').removeClass('col-md-8');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#sidebar').addClass('col-md-4');
        $('#sidebar').addClass('open');
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#content').removeClass('col-md-12');
        $('#content').addClass('col-md-8');
    }
});
```

the only css i had was a hidden class `.hidden{display:none;}` and the [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/N45Kt/) I used xs in the fiddle because of the small window. but works the same.

Comment: Yes, it works but I was really looking for something with some easing/slide effect, to be consistent with the rest of our mocks.

Answer (score 3):

I have used layouting plugin for 2 projects this helped me a lot it gives you full controls. my situation required both left, right and bottom also. link is,

http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

i'v also using bootstrap3 and be wise when using bootstrap modle make shur to put that code on soon after body tag

happy coding.